# iOS Facebook authorization

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions, authorization

Im trying to get authorization to publish stream and get offline access, but I am getting this error.

[image]

And it don't show the permissions that I want to get. My code is below:

```
self.fb = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"offline_access", @"publish_stream", nil];
[self.fb authorize:permissions delegate:self];            
[self.fb dialog:@"oauth" andDelegate:self];
```

Someone can tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just delete the line:

[self.fb dialog:@"oauth" andDelegate:self];

and set the line

[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];

to

[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:NO];